# Not able to reproduce the notepad example in qt; read access violation

Tags: c++, qt

I'm learning Qt following [this link](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/gettingstartedqt.html).

When trying to open a file through function member `open` I get the error:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
this was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

This is the definition of the function:

```
Notepad::open(){
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open File", "", "Text Files (*.txt);;C++ Files (*.cpp *.h");
    if (fileName != "") {
        QFile file(fileName);
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
            QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "Could not open file");
        }
        QTextStream in(&file);
        textEdit->setText(in.readAll());
        //textEdit->setText("test 1a2b");
        file.close();
    }
}
```

Can anybody see the problem?

Comment: Run the program under a debugger. It should show you a call stack that shows exactly where it crashed and you can check who called a member function on a pointer with value `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: Probably the `textEdit` pointer is not valid. You debugger will tell you more. We can't because ther origin of the problem is most likely in nthe code you didn't show.

Comment: Even if your `QFile` object fails to open the given file you still try to process it after closing the message box. You have to exit the function after line with `QMessageBox::critical(...);`.

Comment: Closing parenthesis is missing after `(*.cpp *.h`